# Change the default XtraScrollableControl scrollbar backcolor c# devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm using c# windows forms application , So I Have a simple Form that contain picturebox inside XtraScrollableControl (to Make a PictureBox Scrollable) and it's worked! but i want to change the default design of scrollbar from white or silver  color I think To a specific color Please check below screenshot Thanks.

Regards.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used VScrollBar you can set

```
LookAndFeel.SkinName = Devexpress Dark style;

UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
```